# Windows Assigned to All Desktops Flash When Switching Between Desktops on macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, desktop, window-manager, ventura

On macOS Ventura, when switching between desktops using either the trackpad or the control+arrow shortcut, there is a delay of approximately 1 second before the window on the new desktop takes focus.
This becomes particularly frustrating when using an app that is assigned to "All desktops" because the app is by default at the front until the delay ends. It's like my Mac shows me the new display without restoring its windows state, and restores it only after 1 or 0.5 seconds, after the fingers drag has ended or the keypress has been done.

I haven't found any way to remove this delay or the flashing window that appears. I've seen some people trying to remove switch desktop animations, but they haven't found a solution to this issue. It seems to be a bug in macOS Ventura that wasn't present in some older versions.
This bug completely disallow me from using the "All desktops" feature.

Comment: By the way, using control+1-9 or Cmd+TAB does the same thing, but the delay is much shorter, something like 0.1 second. But the all desktops assigned app window keeps flashing for 0.1 second and it is still annoying, however I notice the flashing behaviour only when going to a desktop that is at the left of the current desktop (when the animation is going left).

Comment: It's not new to Ventura; I can see it on Mojave.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I have seen the bug on Big Sur as well, but Finder only takes focus if it was the last application focused on the old or new desktop.
However, on Ventura, it flashes every time, even if the window hasn't been previously focused.

Comment: hmm… idk. I'd never dream of having Finder assigned to all Spaces, I have it assigned to Space 1 only, so it's not something I'll ever suffer from ;)) [I was annoyed enough when since Sierra clicking any bit of visible Desktop didn't immediately flip back to Finder in Space 1. Apple's desktop/spaces implication has only been downhill ever since.]