# Assigning application to All Desktops causes unfocused windows to be moved to the back on some of my displays

Tags: display, window-manager, spaces, mission-control

I have a multiple display setup with multiple Desktops/Workspaces on each display. I have 'Displays have separate Spaces' and 'Group windows by application' enabled. 'Stage Manager' and the other mission control options are disabled. I'm on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261).

When I have windows of the same application on multiple displays, switching between the windows of that application causes the unfocused windows to be moved behind windows of other applications on some of the displays. If I keep switching until the window is focused again it comes back on top.

This happens when the application is assigned to 'All Desktops'. When it's assigned to 'None' the unfocused windows stay on top on all displays while switching window in focus.

My general experience has been that it's non-primary displays that are affected. However, while trying to recreate it recently with another application than usual it was only the windows on the primary display that were affected.

In addition, I've noticed that when moving a window assigned to "All Desktops" to another display (using Rectangle app) it ends up behind other applications.

I have an impression that the behaviour of hiding unfocused windows assigned to "All Desktops" behind other (unfocused) applications only started with MacOS Ventura.

**I want to be able to view 2 different windows of the same application on different Displays when the application is assigned to "All Desktops".**

There's a screen recording here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JX54OzgUGXXJh4SLrp-eBDi8vLif3Rhp/view
You can see that I never switch from Safari, however when "All Desktops" is active, the Safari gets moved behind Chrome whenever a different Safari window (on another Desktop/Display) is in focus.

Comment: @Allan Thanks, I've clarified what my goal is. I want to be able to have windows of application assigned to "All Desktops" open at the same time on different displays.

Eg, I have Slack assigned to "All Desktops" so that it's always easily available without switching which Desktops are active on a Display. However, if I open a Slack Huddle window and move that window to a Desktop on another Display I'm unable to see both the main Slack window and the huddle window at the same time if there are unfocused windows of another application in the same location.

Comment: I'm not certain what the default behaviour should be for 'separate spaces' *and* All Desktops, but… All Desktops is supposed to be so an app will constantly follow you to every Space you access. You seem to be breaking this manually, by dragging a window to another Space, then wondering why it's not working. I'm not certain what it is you're actually trying to accomplish by this.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'd expect "All Desktops" to only affect which Desktop (workspace) a window is on, not the "order" of windows *within* that desktop. The behaviour of "All Desktops" is to always move the window to the active Desktop on the Display that it is currently on, eg, if I have a window on Desktop 4 which is on Display B and move to Desktop 5 on Display B, the window is moved to Desktop 5. It does this correctly. But depending on the Application and Display it moves the window behind other applications whenever it's not in focus.

Comment: OK. I never use 'separate Spaces', it drives me mad, so wasn't sure of that. But it's always going to affect window order. If it's not in focus, then it's likely to fall behind something that is. Window ordering, per app, was first broken in 10.12 or 10.13 & has never been fixed since. If an app was brought forward it would *always* bring all windows to the same 'layer'. It stopped doing that a long time ago.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you! I switched to "Separate Spaces" because it saves which desktop and display each window is on between disconnecting the displays.

Comment: I can see that makes sense if you have a changing number of displays. Here we have 4 desktops [3 big old Mac Pros & a new iMac] and a single MacBook Pro, none of which ever change their display connections. My Pro is dual screen, all the others are single, so the issue just never arises. :) Part of the issue is that Spaces was great a decade ago, but hasn't ever been looked at properly ever since. When fullscreen was introduced, it started to show 'cracks around the edges' & no-one ever went back to fix them. I've never even looked at Stage Manager, it doesn't appeal to me ;)

Comment: btw, yours isn't the first I've heard about Ventura doing something perhaps slightly different with window ordering on changing Spaces with an 'all desktops' app; but I've never been able to fully repro it here. The only Ventura Mac has a single display.

Comment: Lol, I disabled "Separate Spaces" and got hit by https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458975/windows-assigned-to-all-desktops-flash-when-switching-between-desktops-on-macos

Comment: Ah, yes. That was one of them ;)